# 1-Dimensional Array Counting Same Elements

Tags: c#

I have a 1-dimensional array that fills up a table of 40 random elements (all the values are either 0 or 1).  I want to find the longest consecutive span of values.

For example:

In `111100101` the longest row would be `1111` because it has four consecutive values of `1`.

In `011100` the result is `111`.

I have no idea how to check upon the "next element" and check if it's a 0 or 1. 
Like the first would be 1111 (count 4) but the next would be a 0 value, meaning I have to stop counting.

My idea was placing this value (4) in a other array (example: 111100101), and place the value of the 1's back on zero.  And start the process all over again.

To find the largest value I have made another method that checks up the biggest value in the array that keeps track of the count of 0's 1's, this is not the problem.

But I cannot find a way to fill the array tabelLdr up, having all the values of the group of elements of the same kind (being 0 or 1).

In the code below I have 2 if's and of course it will never go into the second if (to check if the next value in the array is != to its current state (being 0 or 1).

```
public void BerekenDeelrij(byte[] tabel, byte[] tabelLdr) 
{
    byte LdrNul = 0, Ldréén = 0;
    //byte teller = 0;

    for (byte i = 0; i < tabel.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (tabel[i] == 0) 
        {
            LdrNul++;
            //this 2nd if cleary does not work, but i have no idea how to implend this sort of idea in my program.
            if (tabel[i] == 1) //if value != 0 then the total value gets put in the second array tabelLdr, 
            {
                tabelLdr[i] = LdrNul;
                LdrNul = 0
            }
        }

        if (tabel[i] == 1)
        {
            Ldréén++;
            if (tabel[i] == 0)
            {
                tabelLdr[i] = Ldréén;
                Ldréén = 0;
            }
        }

    }/*for*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should do what you need:

```
public int LargestSequence(byte[] array) {
  byte? last = null;
  int count = 0;
  int largest = 0;
  foreach (byte b in array) {
    if (last == b)
      ++count;
    else {
      largest = Math.Max(largest, count);
      last = b;
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  return Math.Max(largest, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even while `i` is the loop counter, it is still just a variable. A valid `for` statement is `for (;;)`, which is an infinite loop. Notice the `for` statement increments `i`, as in `i++`. The expression `i = i + 1` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure if you need the longest "row" of ones or longest row of either 0 or 1. This will work for the latter

```
var max = 0;
var start = 0;
var current = -1;
var count = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<table.Length;i++)
{
   if(current = table[i])
   {
      count++;
   }
   else
   {
      current = table[i];
      if(max < count)
      {
        max = count;
        start = i-count;
      }
      count = 1;
   }
}

 if(max < count)
      {
        max = count;
        start = i-count;
      }
```

//max is the length of the row starting at start;