# Finding 2 positions in a 1-Dimensional Array

Tags: c#

In a method I am calculating the longest row of elements. The 1-dimensional array is filled up with random values (0 or 1).  The method looks up the longest row (being 0 or 1, whatever is the longest).
For example:

In `1110100` the longest row would be 3 (3 * 1)
In `0110000` the longest row would be 4 (4 * 0)

For `1110100` the position in the array would be 0 to 2.
For `0110000` the position in the array would be 3 to 6.

I have been trying with `foreach` loops, `for` loops, etc. but I cannot seem to get the proper indexes of both and cannot seem to display both positions properly.

The longest row of similar elements gets calculated as the following [based on my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891521/1-dimensional-array-counting-same-elements):

```
public int BerekenDeelrij (int [] table)
{
    int count = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int largest = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < tabel.Length; i++)
    {
        if (value == tabel[i])
            counter + +;
        else
        {
            largest = Math.Max largest (largest, counter);
            final value = value
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return Math.Max(largest, counter);
}
```

Comment: Is this code sample supposed to be C#?

Comment: What is that suppose to mean?

Comment: He's asking what language the code is written in. I guess he's asking because it isn't valid C#.

Comment: My execuses, i was putting it in a translator and some wrong things popped in like "final int" hence the reaction.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the `foreach()` with a regular `for(;;)` you immediately have your indices available at the moment you need them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not posting complete code, since this is tagged homework, but a completely different approach to solving this problem, would be to find all the occurrences of consecutive items, and aggregate them into a new array:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ["0", "11", "0000"]
```

Then you could just order that by `item.Length`, descending, select top 1 item, i.e. "0000"

After that, join the aggregated array

```
["0", "11", "0000"] => "0110000"
```

And from there, return `joinedResult.IndexOf( longestItem )` and that index + `longestItem.Length`

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. Although it makes perfect sence what your saying, i'm afraid i am not that deep into C# yet and looking for a more "direct approach". Regards.